# Java subtracting Generic values The operator minus is undefined

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to subtract the value from a provided array (2D Array). I would like to do by using Generics. Can anyone help what is wrong with my code. I mean do I need to extend some class? I am getting the error (The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T)

Thanks in advance.

```
//this method Subtracts Value from the given Matrix for all the rows but for given columns 
private <T> void subtractValueFromColumns(T[][] matrix,
        ArrayList<Integer> columnsIndex, T value) {

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnsIndex.size(); j++){
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] - value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So what happens if I call: `subtractValueFromColumns(new String[][] {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}, new ArrayList<Integer>(), "z")`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define operations and methods that can be used on that given type.

```
public interface ArithmeticOps<T extends ArithmeticOps<T>>
{
    T add(T other);
    T subtract(T other);
    T divide(T other);
    T multiply(T other);
}

private <T extends ArithmeticOps<T>> void subtractValueFromColumns(T[][] matrix,
        List<Integer> columnsIndex, T value) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnsIndex.size(); j++){
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j].subtract(value);
        }
    }
}
```

It is similar to how LibGDX does its Vector operations.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector.java

```
 public interface Vector<T extends Vector<T>> {
    /** Scales this vector by a scalar
     * @param scalar The scalar
     * @return This vector for chaining */
    T scl (float scalar);

    T add (T v);
}
```

and

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java

```
public class Vector2 implements Serializable, Vector<Vector2> {
    @Override
    public Vector2 scl (float x, float y) {
        this.x *= x;
        this.y *= y;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Vector2 add (Vector2 v) {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without casting (which more or less means that Generics is useless here).

The `-` operator can be only applied to numeric types, but at compile-time the compiler cannot be aware of the runtime type of the generic type `T`.

---

As a workaround I can suggest using the `BigDecimal` type and it's nested arithmetic methods (like `.subtract()`)

```
private void subtractValueFromColumns(BigDecimal[][] matrix,
        ArrayList<Integer> columnsIndex, BigDecimal value) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnsIndex.size(); j++){
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j].subtract(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This has a downside effect, though. In order to use the method properly, you will be forced to convert your numeric variables to `BigDecimal` and vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

`-` is only defined for a few types like `int` and those that can be converted / unboxed like `Integer`. Subtracting will not work with generic types since Java has no way of knowing whether a type `T` can be converted to e.g. `int`. Java has also no operator overloading which means that you can't define a meaning for that operator later on for arbitrary types.

You can however restrict `T` to something that has for example a `minus(T other)` method and use that instead. You could also use `Number` instead of `T` and use the `.doubleValue()` to do your math.

Another possibility is to let clients of this method define how the operation works like so:

```
interface Operation<T> {
    T apply(T one, T two);
}

private <T> void subtractValueFromColumns(T[][] matrix,
        ArrayList<Integer> columnsIndex, T value, Operation<T> op) {

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnsIndex.size(); j++){
            matrix[i][j] = op.apply(matrix[i][j], value);
        }
    }
}
```